# frequency Domain with bandlimit

Tags: frequency-spectrum, frequency-domain, bandpass

May I ask why does the frequency Domain Picture of a signal look like that? Is the signal built with many different frequencies? [image]

Comment: The answer is "because that is what your signal is". This is a continuous spectrum, which means this signal is not composed of *many* different frequencies, because that would imply that it's somehow periodic, but that it's s non-periodic signal. You are basically asking "what is the Fourier transform", without realizing it. And that question is best answered with a consistently written textbook, not with a stackexchange answer.

Comment: _"Is the signal built with many different frequencies?"_ yes, that's what the Fourier transform is about, but interpretation of "frequencies" may be tricky. [Recommended.](https://youtu.be/spUNpyF58BY)

Comment: Where is this plot from? Do you have any link for context?

Comment: @Jdip https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment

> why the shape in the frequency domain looks like a bell shape.

Like @MarcusMuller said: **because it looks like that**

Yes, if you want, you can say that's because multiple different frequencies combine together. Since $X(f)$ is continuous, it's actually an infinite number of frequencies **with different contributions** that combine together to give you this specific shape. Other signals have frequencies that combine differently and give you different shapes in the frequency domain like triangle, square etc

---

As a side note, if whoever made the plot intended to show the **magnitude response**
$$\lvert X(f) \rvert$$ as opposed to the **frequency response** $$X(f)$$ Since $\lvert X(f) \rvert$ is symmetric, that would imply a real signal $x(t)$.

However, if indeed the picture intended to show the frequency response $X(f)$, then since $X(f)$ is **even** (but could be real or imaginary), that implies that $x(t)$ is either real and even ($X(f)$ real and even), or imaginary and even ($X(f)$ imaginary and even).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your explanation. May I ask how can I know the X(f) is even or odd?

Comment: The link you provided shows that it’s indeed a magnitude spectrum. Since it’s even symmetric, that means $x(t)$ is real. If you’re not sure what even or odd means, I suggest you google it!

Comment: But basically if it’s symmetric about the y-axis, it’s even. If it’s symmetric about the origin, it’s odd.

Answer (score 0):

But the continuous Fourier transform GIVES us a continuous curve in the frequency domain for any signal $x(t)$.

Most probably your signal $x(t)$ has some symmetry in the time domain and that is why in the frequency domain we get a even signal $X(\omega)$

Comment: Yep but what I mean is why the shape of the frequency graph look like that

Comment: @kidox editted.

Comment: Perhaps u misunderstood what I mean. What i actually want to know is why the shape in the frequency domain looks like a bell shape, instead of triangle, square or rectangle square. Is it because multiple different frequency combine together or ?

Comment: I cant tell that without seeing the signal in the time domain .You have to give us the signal in the time domain.

Comment: "... why the shape in the frequency domain looks like ...".  Please _edit your question_ with this desired information.  Stackexchange likes consistent self-contained questions that can be fully understood without reading the comments -- and they want their answers the same way.

Comment: _This particular_ shape looks that way because someone wanted to make a point about arbitrary signals, so they drew a squiggly line that's symmetrical around $f=0$ to make that point.  Different signals certainly have different spectra, though.